# Inmobi Interstitial didn't close

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inmobi

I'm using inmobi unity plugin for ad but facing one problem after show "Interstitial" by using function `InMobiAndroid.showInterstitial()` I'm not able to close it I press so many times on close button but ad not close what to do?

```
if((string.Compare(InMobiAndroid.getInterstitialState(), "Ready") == 0 || string.Compare(InMobiAndroid.getInterstitialState(),"READY") == 0)&& !loadAd)
{
    InMobiAndroid.showInterstitial();
    loadAd = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the Android Manifest file

Add

```
 <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
```

in the

```
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
```